# Как записать в переменную данные из combobox и использовать их в linq запросе к БД?

Tags: c#, combobox, linq2sql

```
 '   string b;
     public void Combo1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         b = combo1.Items[combo1.SelectedIndex].ToString();  
    }
     private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                    var query12 = (
                    from CPU in dataEntities.CPUs
                    where CPU.Manufacturer == a || CPU.Series == b
                    select new { CPU.Soket }).Distinct();
                    combo2.ItemsSource = query12.ToList();
        }'
```

Comment: Проверил что записывается в пременную b { Series = Ryzen 5         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly List<string> _manufacturer = new List<string> { "Intel", "AMD" };

        private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _sockets = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "AMD", new List<string> { "AM2", "AM3", "AM4", } },
            { "Intel", new List<string> { "LGA1150", "LGA1151", } },
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.DataSource = _manufacturer;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Enabled = false;

            try
            {
                var sockets = _sockets
                    .Where(x => x.Key == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    .Select(x => x.Value)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

                comboBox2.DataSource = sockets;
            }
            finally
            {
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот рабочий пример (без БД). Не знаю форматы данных, которые ты тянешь с базы, так как вижу только часть кода. В данном случае тебе не нужно событие **MainWindow_Load**, потому что **SelectedIndexChanged** выполнится всё равно при первичной отрисовке, в нем и тяни из базы данные для заполнения **comboBox2**, в идеале асинхронно, конечно. Не помню уже, вызывает ли запрос к контексту исключение, но на всякий случай обернул в try/finally. Если больше подробностей приведёшь, доведём до ума твой код может :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, MainWindow_Load и правда оказался не нужным, а данны в переменной я скорректировал с помощью команд Remove и Replace)

Comment: Ну хорошо, что всё получилось. Я бы ещё порекомендовал тебе linq-запрос не разделять (.ToList() - у тебя отдельно), тебе тогда среда разработки подскажет сразу в переменной, куда это всё кладётся, что будет на выходе, в противном случае метаться по коду придётся, хотя, конечно, на любителя.